# R seems duplicated() to select the wrong duplicates

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates, conditional-statements, data-cleaning

I've noticed a couple of times now that when I'm using R to identify duplicates, sometimes it seems to identify the wrong cases.

Here's a data frame that has three columns, each which may be holding duplicate values. I want to isolate the cases that are duplicates of another case on all three variables.

```
set.seed(100)
test <- data.frame(id = sample(1:15, 20, replace = TRUE),
                     cat1 = sample(letters[1:2], 20, replace = TRUE),
                     cat2 = sample(letters[1:2], 20, replace = TRUE))
```

Which gives me:

```
   id cat1 cat2
1   5    b    a
2   4    b    b
3   9    b    b
4   1    b    b
5   8    a    b
6   8    a    a
7  13    b    b
8   6    b    b
9   9    b    a
10  3    a    a
11 10    a    a
12 14    b    a
13  5    a    a
14  6    b    a
15 12    b    b
16 11    b    a
17  4    a    a
18  6    b    a
19  6    b    b
20 11    a    a
```

I've tried this a couple of ways, such as:
`duplicated(test$id) & duplicated(test$cat1) & duplicated(test$cat2)`

But this just results in the same as `duplicated(test$id)`:

```
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
[17]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

So instead I tried `duplicated(test$id, test$cat1, test$cat2)`, which produces different results:

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[17] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

But is still incorrect - if I call these cases from the data frame we get:

```
> test[which(duplicated(test$id, test$cat1, test$cat2)),]
   id cat1 cat2
1   5    b    a
2   4    b    b
3   9    b    b
5   8    a    b
8   6    b    b
14  6    b    a
16 11    b    a
18  6    b    a
```

As you can see these are not the rows we should be getting (were it doing what I'd have thought it would do), which should be (as far as I can see):

```
18  6   b   a
19  6   b   b
```

Does anyone know why it's coming up with these results, and where I'm going wrong using it? Is there a simple (ideally non-verbose) way of doing this?

Comment: Using `tidyverse` I've just tried this:
`test1 <- test %>%
         filter(!(duplicated(id) | duplicated(cat1) | duplicated(cat2)))`
Which reads to me "filter results that are not a duplicate of id OR cat1 OR cat2, which I would have thought would have worked, but this just  comes up with one result (5 b a) which is not a duplicate either.

Answer (score 2):

We need to apply `duplicated` on a `data.frame` or `matrix` or `vector`

```
i1 <- duplicated(test[c('id', 'cat1')])
i2 <- duplicated(cbind(test$id, test$cat1))
identical(i1, i2)
#[1] TRUE
```

and not on more than one `data.frame` or `matrix` or `vector`

```
i3 <- duplicated(test$id, test$cat1)
identical(i1, i3)
#[1] FALSE
```

---

It is specified in the documents of `?duplicated`

> duplicated(x, incomparables = FALSE, ...)

where

> x a vector or a data frame or an array or NULL.

and not 'x1', 'x2', etc..

As @Aaron mentioned in the comments, to subset the duplicates from the OP's data

```
test[duplicated(test),]
```

and if we wanted only the duplicates, then

```
test[duplicated(test)|duplicated(test, fromLast = TRUE),]
```

Comment: Good explanation, though I suggest adding the code that would actually find the duplicates from the OP's example (`test[duplicated(test),]`)

Answer (score 1):

Taking duplicates of columns separately is not the same as taking duplicates of a data frame or matrix. This example makes it more clear:

```
df = data.frame(x = c(1,2,1),
                y = c(1,3,3))
df$dupe = duplicated(df$x) & duplicated(df$y)
df$dupe2 = duplicated(df[,c("x","y")])
df
```

Using your method, `duplicated` says "When I hit the third row, x already had a 1 so it's duplicated. y already had a 3 so it's duplicated." This doesn't mean that it already saw a row where x = 1 and y = 3.

Comment: Good explanation, though I suggest adding the code that would actually find the duplicates from the OP's example (`test[duplicated(test),]`)